# I tried to record 24 green bar in br but I failed

Tags: arrays, pine-script

```
n = input(24,title = "n")
gap = high - low
ret = close - open
greenbar = ret > 0
redbar = ret < 0
sr = array.new_float(0)
br = array.new_float(0) 
for i = 0 to n-1 by 1
    if greenbar[i]
        array.push( br, high[i] - low[i]) 
plot(array.get(br ,1) )
```

Im new in pinescript and I tried to record 24 green bar in br but I failed...

Answer (score 0):

There are some cases where the `br` array will have less than 2 elements, and therefore there will be no element in position 1. You can check this before plotting:

```
n = input.int(24, title = "n")
gap = high - low
ret = close - open
greenbar = ret > 0
redbar = ret < 0
sr = array.new_float(0)
br = array.new_float(0) 

for i = 0 to n-1 by 1
    if greenbar[i]
        array.push(br, high[i] - low[i]) 

plot(array.size(br) > 2 ? array.get(br, 1) : na )
```